# Disable recent text lists in browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I am working on a .NET application using C#. When a user starts deleting text from a textbox the browser shows a small list (almost like a drop down list) of recently entered data. The project owners what this removed. I believe it is done automatically by the browser because I never recorded data or implemented this in my design. Does anyone know the name of this built in feature or even more precisely how to disable it entirely (preferably across all browers). If at all possible I would like to accomplish this on the client side in JQuery. I say this because there are places where I dynamically add textboxes.

Comment: check this SO Question : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off `autocomplete`.

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" autocomplete="off" />
```

Take a look [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion).

Comment: Should I turn autocomplete off for the form, each textbox or both?

Comment: @JBone, that's up to you. I posted a good article that explains the difference.

Comment: @JBone http://wufoo.com/html5/ this attribute is not supported in all browsers